# Forcing an iPhone app to quit when Home button is pressed (on iOS4)

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, background

I do not want my app to switch to the "task bar" when the Home button is pressed. That's why I would like it to be closed upon Home press. I added this entry to the info.plist file but this does not change the behaviour:

application does not run in background

(and I checked the box...)

I rebuilt the whole app both in debug and release mode but no way. I heard of another key which should be added to the info.plist but I cannot add it through Xcode:

UIApplicationExitsOnSuspend

What is the right way to do that ?

Regards,

Franz

Comment: In fact, I have just checked: "application does not run in background" is the same as the key "UIApplicationExitsOnSuspend". "application does not run in the background" is just the human-readable form.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

On iOS 4, multitasking is enabled in Xcode projects by default. This prevents the `applicationWillTerminate` method from being called. If you do not want to support multitasking, place `UIApplicationExitsOnSuspend` in your MyAppName-Info.plist file and check the checkbox. If you do want to support it, place any code in the `applicationDidEnterBackground` delegate method that you want to execute before the application enters an inactive state.

Answer (score 1):

What you're doing will indeed stop the application from running in the background, but you can't prevent it from going to the multitasking bar still. Sorry.

Comment: Indeed, the execution stops and the app *fully" restarts when pressing the icon (from the task bar or from the desktop). Thank you for your clarification.

Answer (score 1):

You can manually close the application after home button is pressed. When home button is pressed `applicationDidEnterBackground` is called. In this delegate just write `exit(0)` and your application will be ended instantly.

Comment: If you use this method, your app will be rejected.

Comment: No it will not be rejected if you gave user indication that its going to close the app. I have submitted the app to app store with this feature.